# Show Regulation Messages on Stack Exchange App

Tags: feature-request, closed-questions, historical-lock, on-hold, ios-app

Questions like [What is your best programmer joke?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/234075/what-is-your-best-programmer-joke/234518#234518) are locked (or closed, or on hold, etc.) which is clearly stated when using the website version of Stack Exchange.  This message does not appear on the app.

I think it would be awesome if it were added to the app.  (In order to prevent foolish questions like [Donation of Bounty](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/281522/donation-of-bounty) for example.)

Comment: Confusing as much on Android app too. Compared to close reason which can be displayed on the app, the lock only mentions date, not the reason.

Comment: Probably should be posted/migrated on Meta.SE instead.